# Git hook not completing on Github Desktop for mac

Tags: git, githooks, github-desktop

My hook works fine on git CLI.

Adding `echo 'Running precommit hook' > ~/Desktop/hello.txt` to the hook makes that file appear when I commit with the GUI, so pre-commit is running.

However my next line in the hook is `gulp --production`.
That never seems to run, and I can't establish why.

Including the full path to gulp `/usr/local/bin/gulp --production` doesn't fix it.

Replacing shebang `#!/bin/sh` with `#!/usr/bin/env sh` doesn't fix it.

.git/hooks/pre-commit permissions are `-rwxr-xr-x`.